# Python - Regex to ignore anything within <>

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to get a URL such as `http://www.test.com` within `body`which is the contents of a email.

However, there can also be URLs in this format: `<http://www.test.com>` I am trying to edit the following regular expression to ignore anything within these symbols`<>`

```
url = re.search('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', body)
```

Comment: It might be easier not to use regex for this.

Comment: What would be your alternative? I was thinking maybe trying to strip everything within <> before passing the string into the regular expression?

Comment: This can be done with a very, very easy change. Search for "regex lookarounds". Or just regex tutorials in general. Your regex is overcomplicated and redundant, and almost certainly has a bug you haven't noticed (hint: The `-` in `[$-_@.&+]`)

Comment: Maybe looking for pairs of `<` and `>` and excising everything in between. But it might end up being more verbose than the regex answer already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing this with RegEx, then this can be accomplished using a [negative lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
(?<!<)
```

Thus the full regular expression will look like:

```
(?<!<)http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

Comment: Ah yes I'm reading a lookaround tutorial right now! Works perfectly thank you!